# 戻り値のみ違う関数のオーバーロードについて

Tags: c++

下記、std::vectorのbeginの定義ですが、タイトルの通り戻り値のみ違う、引数が同じ関数のオーバーロードをしていると思います。
オーバーロードは普通引数が違う関数でないとエラーが出ると思うのですが、これはどういった仕組で定義されているのでしょうか。

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY iterator               begin() _NOEXCEPT;
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY const_iterator         begin()   const
_NOEXCEPT;
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY iterator               end() _NOEXCEPT;
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY const_iterator         end()     const      _NOEXCEPT;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JIS X 3014:2003 13.1 多重定義可能な宣言の２項
- 返却値の型だけが異なる関数宣言は、多重定義することができない
- 同じ名前及び同じ仮引数型をもつ複数のメンバ関数宣言であって [snip]
  暗黙のオブジェクト仮引数の型が異なれば、それらのメンバ関数宣言は、多重定義することができる

`vector::begin()` と `vector::begin() const` は暗黙の仮引数 `this` の constness が異なります。
提示 `vector` [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ソースを [c](/questions/tagged/c) っぽく暗黙の `this` を明示するなら

```
iterator vector_begin(vector* const this) { ... }
const_iterator vector_begin(const vector* const this) { ... }
```

となり、関数名は同じでも引数の型が異なるためオーバーロード可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。省略された引数でオーバーロードを実現させていることは理解しました。「暗黙のオブジェクト仮引数の型が異なれば」オブジェクト仮引数は初めて知ったのですが、これはどういった条件で定義されるのですか？

Comment: `this` のことですか？　非静的メンバ関数ならば必ず暗黙のオブジェクト仮引数 `this` を持ちます。そして非 `const` メンバ関数なら（最後に `const` がついていないメンバ関数) 暗黙の `this` の型は `T* const this` であり `const` メンバ関数なら `const T* const this` となります。